# Twilio Answering Machine detection

Tags: node.js, twilio

I'm a developer of firmware at a startup in Paris. We are using Twilio for our product and we want to stop the call when it's a voice machine, thus we've used `IfMachine` parameter, but without any result.

We wish you can help us with this. Below is the code we use (Node.js); please see if we use the parameter in the right way.

I read in some forums that `IfMachine` works only in the USA, I wish have that is not true.

Regards.

```
Client.calls.create({
url: returnXmlUrlFile(textToSpeech),
to: userData.phoneNumber,
from: "+339xxxxxxxx",
IfMachine = "Hangup",
Method = "POST",
timeout: 11,

statusCallback: apiCoassistTwilioStatusCallbackHelper
}, function(err, call)
```

Comment: Hi, I think the code you tried to post didn't go through. Can you update the question again with the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reverse engineer it as I have described in [this post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/02/tracking-call-status-how-can-you-tell-if-a-human-answers-the-phone-2.html).

Using the [`<Gather>` verb](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather) you can choose to continue call flow only when a human answers the phone by building in IVR behavior as you'll find in this [Node.js tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/ivr-phone-tree/node/express#2).

```
twiml.gather({
    action: "/path-to-message-for-people",
}
```

**March 2017 Update**:

We now have [enhanced Answering Machine Detection](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/03/introducing-new-answering-machine-detection.html).

For example, the `MachineDetection` parameter can be `Enable` or `DetectMessageEnd`. `Enable` returns results as soon as recognition is complete. `DetectMessageEnd` will wait until after a greeting to return results if an answering machine is detected.

Using new AMD would look like this as seen [in the docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/answering-machine-detection):

```
curl 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX123456789/Calls.json' -X POST \
--data-urlencode 'To=+1562300000' \
--data-urlencode 'From=+18180000000' \
--data-urlencode 'MachineDetection=Enable' \
--data-urlencode 'Url=https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/EH8ccdbd7f0b8fe34357da8ce87ebe5a16' \
-u ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX123456789:[AuthToken]
```